# "I belong to a greater stage"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is it okay to say:

> I believe I belong to a greater stage.

Basically, I want to say that I want to transit from my current position to a better one since I think I am skillful enough for the better opportunity.

I know it's usually *belong to*, but this *to* here doesn't seem right.

I think the sentence should be fine from the grammar perspective. But do people normally say this?

Comment: It is not clear what your sentence means. *Stage* can mean at least 14 different things.

Comment: What I want to say is basically I want to transit from the current position to a better one since I think I am skillful enough for the better opportunity.

Comment: Well, language can be pretty *context specific*, and your added explanation can still refer to many contexts. For instance, one could be talking about a career path, a skill level, a course level. If I guess that *position* means something like *job*, then perhaps the most diplomatic way to put it is *I believe I'm ready for a greater challenge.* It also depends who you are talking to, your boss or your friend.

Comment: It's all to do with the preposition, folks.

Comment: WHY THE HELL do people type "sth" instead of "something" these days?  Who started this stupid fad?  Rappers?

Comment: @JoeBlow do you understand sthu? It's kind of like sth. Oh, *sth* is found in most dictionaries. As is *sb*.

Comment: I understand it, but I wanna know why it is used.  I have many colleagues in China and I've noticed it is, perhaps, particularly popular w/ people from China, writing in English.  I wonder if it was popularised by some particular event (like the pop music star popularised "4u" with an album cover, as I understand it.)

Comment: *Sth., sb., so., adj.* and dozens more are all common abbreviations to be found in most every dictionary going back centuries. It is little wonder that people actually use actual words they actually find in an actual dictionary.

Comment: Back to the original question, it is simply not right that it's usually "belong to". You can belong on, belong after, belong between, belong before, belong in, and you can simply belong. The choice of the preposition is determined not by *belong*, but by what follows (or does not follow) it.

Comment: Regarding abbreviations, slang exists; "txt style writing" exists.  Some people think txt-style writing is infuriating. Some people think bold-caps is infuriating.  In each case, it is utterly vacuous to point out "oh, that's called an abbreviation" or "oh, that's done with markup".

Comment: Regarding Back to the original question, indeed, it depends on the sense of "stage" --- exactly as CarSmack said in the very first comment. (is there a word for "the first offhand comment on a thread is more astute than all the rest" ?  :) )

Comment: (referring to self) This fish belongs in a bigger pond. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+big+fish+in+a+small+pond

Answer (score 2):

You (rightly) belong **on** a greater stage.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @CarSmack and with @Kris. If you use stage, people move on stages, climb onto stages, perform on stages, move onto bigger stages and belong on a greater stage.

All writing is done for an audience, and the most important thing is to be certain that the person(s) reading the letter will understand what you've written.

If you want to move on to a different stage of your career, then it's *to move on to the next stage*.

> I believe I'm ready to move on to the next stage in/of my career.

If that means you want more responsibility, one might say

> I'm ready to take on greater responsibilit(y/ies).

Comment: "I'm ready to move on to the next stage" is a perfect and beautiful sentence, as Medica says.  However.  it's possible that's not what Jane is wanting to say.  Stating that "I belong to a much greater stage" has a hugely different sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, uses of "stage" and phrases like "take to the stage..."

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x22wu0_pet-shop-boys-left-to-my-own-device_music

(famous usage at about 3') have many very different meanings.

Astoundingly, nobody has mentioned that a lot of this all comes from

```
All the world's a stage baby,
And all the men and women merely players.
They have their exits and their entrances,
And one man in his time plays many parts....
A babbling baby, a fucked-up kid.
A stupid career-man chasing paper.
Fawning husband, idiot townsman.
And eventually as useless as a newborn all over again.
And then dead as dust.
```

When Shakespeare sed "all the world's a stage" he really evokes "stage" as a "theatre of life".

(It's hard to express the idea without just using another analogous word...it's a typically Shakespearean, incredible, consciousness-altering use of language.)

Note that the very prosaic interpretation of your sentence, is simply that your career is moving to the next stage == "nest step", "next phase", 'next year" of your career.

If that is what you mean, you should use the sentence Medica has stated, **I'm ready to move on to the next stage of my career."

You're simply saying "I'm ready for a promotion" "ready for the next mission, step, section" of my career.

## But.

Because you use the word "greater", you truly signal the tremendously broader, Shakespearean meaning of "stage"

## And.

When you use "belong", you REALLY signal you are implying the tremendously broader, Shakespearean meaning of "stage"

Now as a matter of fact, IF YOU MEAN the tremendously broader, Shakespearean meaning of "stage",

If you are standing there, like Nietzsche, saying "I belong to an entirely different universe ...."

in fact "to" is the correct word.

If "the stage" means "showbusiness", it is "I belong to the stage".  If "the stage" has the full, whoa-dude, tremendously broader, Shakespearean meaning, it is "I belong to the stage".

If you simply mean the "next mission at the company, next step in your career path" then you can't use the word **belong**, you'd say "for" or similar: "I'm ready for the next stage of my career."